# How to use str_replace, WordPress hooks, and WooCommerce functions

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, woocommerce

In WooCommerce there is the main template which everything runs off.

Here: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/woocommerce-template.php#L1315

At `line 1315` and down we begin the html for a checkout, but the problem is everything is in a `<p>` tag. I want to change it to a `<div>` or `<li>` or `<dd>` (undecided). Nonetheless, I want to alter the tag.

I am hoping to do it via a `str_replace("<p","<div",$some_variable);` and a `str_replace("/p>","/div>",$some_variable);` but am seriously confused on what hook to be calling.

Oh, and the reason I'm not editing the main file is since every update for the plugin it would be overwritten and inefficient :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the Switch you can edit the if statement to look like this replacing 
line 1468

From:

```
if ( $args['return'] ) return $field; else echo $field;
```

To:

```
if ( $args['return'] ) {
    str_replace("<p","<div",$field);
    str_replace("/p>","/div>",$field);
    return $field;
} else {
    str_replace("<p","<div",$field);
    str_replace("/p>","/div>",$field);
    echo $field;
}
```

Or you can add it to each **case** before the **break**

```
case "country" :

    ...
    ...
    ...

    str_replace("<p","<div",$field);
    str_replace("/p>","/div>",$field);
break;
```

---

You can try and edit the template

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

> you can edit these files in an upgrade safe way through overrides.
>   Simply copy it into a directory within your theme named /woocommerce,
>   keeping the same file structure.
>
> Example: To overide the admin order notification, copy:
>   woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to
>   yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php
>
> The copied file will now override the WooCommerce default template
>   file. Do not edit these files within the core plugin itself as they
>   are overwritten during the upgrade process and any customisations will
>   be lost.

Comment: There's no way to hook into it? To add to wordpress' functions.php?

Comment: I would go with my last update and go that route.  Woocommerce is setup with do_action for every hook so I do not think you can bind that to a plugin/variable to have it output differently.  You can recreate the template file instead to have it output what you want though.

Comment: I'm still unclear on how to do it 'cause the do_action links to the woocommerce_template.php file. But if I'm thinking correctly, would you suggest replacing the `do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' );` hook in the form-checkout.php with a custom one in my function.php with the contents from woocommerce-template.php?

Comment: Yes essentially if you do not want to edit the plugin data as we all know is not a good idea, you would have to create your own do_action in replacement of what is there already.  Basically create your own function and hooks that directly interact with woocommerce.  You can use this as a reference as well http://docs.woothemes.com/document/hooks/

Comment: Personally I do not know of a method but you may be able to get away with using a add_filter to the do_action as a separate function and return the str_replace() from it in a separate plugin. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: Okay so I'm struggling how to remove the action: `remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details',array( &$woocommerce, 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ), 99999 );`

Comment: Instead of removing the action I would recreate the template (As I stated in my answer) and not add the do_action for the checkout and instead would use the existing hooks that I have noted in my previous comment and output the appropriate fields.